# Why isn't mkdir -p working right in a script called by checkinstall?

Tags: linux, mkdir, checkinstall

I'm trying to compile [Quarter](http://www.coin3d.org/lib/quarter) and package it using [checkinstall](http://www.asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/).

If I do the standard ./configure && make && sudo make install, things go fine.

```
$ wget http://ftp.coin3d.org/coin/src/all/Quarter-1.0.0.tar.gz
$ tar xzf Quarter-1.0.0.tar.gz
$ cd Quarter-1.0.0
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

But when I use checkinstall, it fails on a `mkdir -p` that should work perfectly fine.  The way it fails is exactly how it would as if the `-p` option weren't given.  This is the checkinstall command line I'm using:

```
$ checkinstall -D -y --install=no --pkgname=libquarter --pkgversion=1.0.0 \
  --arch=i386 --pkglicense=GPL --maintainer=me@example.com --reset-uids=yes
```

This is the failure:

```
....
/bin/bash ../../../cfg/mkinstalldirs /usr/local/include/Quarter/devices
mkdir -p -- /usr/local/include/Quarter/devices
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/include/Quarter': No such file or directory
make[4]: *** [install-libdevicesincHEADERS] Error 1
....
```

This is the relevant part of the script:

```
$ cat cfg/mkinstalldirs
....
case $dirmode in
  '')
    if mkdir -p -- . 2>/dev/null; then
      echo "mkdir -p -- $*"
      exec mkdir -p -- "$@"
    fi
    ;;
....
```

<s>I don't understand why that `exec` is there -- doesn't that guarantee that the remainder of the script (after the `esac`) will never execute?</s> (If the `if` test passes, then the script assumes `mkdir -p` works correctly, so once it does the real `mkdir -p` it can quit; otherwise the remainder of the script implements proper `mkdir -p` behavior.)  <s>I also don't understand why it uses `"$*"` in the echo and `"$@"` in the next line, but it doesn't seem to matter -- they're both the same thing since this script is being called with just one argument.</s> (Tom explained in comment.)

If I add two lines between `echo` and `exec` that does `mkdir -p -- "$@"` and then `echo "Now doing the exec mkdir..."` then it works like this -- better, but still bewildering:

```
/bin/bash ../../../cfg/mkinstalldirs /usr/local/include/Quarter/devices
mkdir -p -- /usr/local/include/Quarter/devices
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/include/Quarter': No such file or directory
Now doing the exec mkdir...
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 InputDevice.h /usr/local/include/Quarter/devices/InputDevice.h
.... finishes successfully!
```

Now, the fact that doing the mkdir line twice made it work tells me it's not a permissions issue (beside, that would generate a different diagnostic from mkdir, and this is being run as `sudo`, and it's actually working in `/var/tmp/...` not the real `/usr/local/...`).  I think what's happening is that the first mkdir invocation (the one I added) is actually creating just the `Quarter` directory and bailing out, and then when the second mkdir runs, it's able to create the `devices` subdirectory, because the Quarter directory is already there.  But why would mkdir work that way???

My workaround is to patch that mkinstalldirs script somehow, but I'm really curious why this is breaking!

This is a Ubuntu 10.10 guest running in VirtualBox on Win7, checkinstall version 1.6.2 installed thru apt-get.

---

**EDIT:**
I did some testing to see what works and what fails in this environment...

```
mkdir -p /foo works correctly
mkdir -p /foo && mkdir -p /foo/bar works correctly
mkdir -p foo/bar works correctly
mkdir /foo/bar failed as expected (correct)
mkdir foo/bar failed as expected (correct)
mkdir -p /foo/bar fails
```

Weird that `-p` works for relative pathnames but not for absolute pathnames.  Or maybe the correct distinction is that `-p` works outside of the "chroot" tree (if it's even really using chroot) but not within it.

I also verified that despite the failure, it is able to create the first directory level.

Still a mystery.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's actually working in /tmp/... not the real /usr/local/..."? Chroot?

Comment: FWIW, i imagine the use of $* in the echo is so that echo is given one parameter containing the whole command line, rather than the N parameters, one for each argument, it would get if $@ was used. It's a very minor neatness and efficiency thing. It does look weird sitting right next to a use of $@, though.

Comment: @Tom, that would be my guess.  I need to sudo for it to work at all, but it's not doing a real install (which is what I wanted since I just want to create the package).  Not sure why I have to sudo at all, but I can live with it.  And thanks for the explanation of $* vs. $@!

Comment: @tom there's a difference between `"$*"` and `"$@"`

Comment: @Tom, I'm reading thru the checkinstall source, looks like it's intercepting calls like mkdir() etc. and replacing them with its own versions.  Must be a bug in there somewhere.  So it's probably not using chroot.

Comment: This is [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/checkinstall/+bug/78455).

Comment: Just stumbled on this mkdir -p absolute path limitation. Quite annoying. But in your last comment you say "Despite the failure, it is able to create the first directory level" but that isn't happening for me. If that were the case then you could just run the same command a few times until it piecemealed each directory step, but that isn't happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mkdir -p` isn't working like it should because it's a checkinstall version of mkdir, not the "true" mkdir.  Must be some bug in checkinstall that makes it work a bit differently.

This patch works around the bug:

```
./configure
sed -i 's/if mkdir .*-p --.*; then/if false; then ## &/' cfg/mkinstalldirs
....
```

Answer (score 23):

Using

```
checkinstall --fstrans=no
```

should fix this.
Or

```
Set "TRANSLATE=0"
```

in `/etc/checkinstallrc` and try again.

Comment: It was fixed it checkinstall git long time ago but its still not in release version. Anyway, this is great tip.

Comment: Obviously this doesn't work if you need file system translation, i.e. if you don't have root access. Not so much a fix but a very limiting workaround.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i -e 's/TRANSLATE=1/TRANSLATE=0/g' /etc/checkinstallrc
```